# Does there exist an invertible nonlinear function in $GF(p)$?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, finite-fields

Given $GF(p)$, does there exist a *nonlinear* function $y=f_a(x)$ such that every element $x\in GF(p)$ uniquely maps to an element $y\in GF(p)$ ?

Of course, $y=x$ is a trivial linear example. However, when I plot $f_a(x_a), \cdots, f_a(x_p)$, I want the result to *appear* random, similar like the scatter plot in https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c3/Polynomial_over_a_finite_field_as_per_SSSS.png but no two values of $x$ must generate the same $y$ (in other words, the output space must include all elements).

If possible, the parameter $a$ should parameterize the function such that a different, randomly looking behavior is obtained.

Comment: Look up the concept of *symmetric group*.

Comment: What about $x\mapsto x+1$? Do you count it as 'linear'? Then just swap any two elements.

Comment: @Berci Yes, this I count as linear. When I plot f(x) vs linearly increasing x the result should "look" random (as in the linked scatterplot). f(x)=x+1 would give me a ramp (or sawtooth). I think the swapping part is what I want to avoid.

Comment: @Mindlack Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is crucial that the multiplicative group of $GF(p)$ has size $p-1.$ Using this, for example one can prove that the following are *permutation polynomials* whenever $\gcd(k,p-1)=1$ and $a\in GF(p):$
$$
f_{k,a}(x)= x^{k}+a
$$
This gives you a parameter space of size $\varphi(p-1)$ if you vary over the exponents $k$ (since you stated you wanted to obtain a collection of such mappings, where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient).

More generally, the collection of Dickson's polynomials
$$
D_k(x,a)=\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}\frac{n}{n-j} \binom{n-j}{j}(-a)^j x^{n-2j} 
$$
are permutation polynomials for all $k\geq 1$ and $a\in GF(p)$ arbitrary.